# Unassigned variable in return statement

Tags: c#, datatable, sqlclient

for some reason I don't seem to be able to put the return in a fashion that captures this stored procedure's return value (0 or -1), either it returns the value which was used to initialize the variable or keeps telling me the local variable is unassigned.

```
public int changePass(int idUsuario, String old_pass, String new_pass)
{
    int result;

    try
    {
        DataTable tablaResultado =
            DataBaseAccess.advanceStoredProcedureRequest(
                "pa_usuario_change_pass",
                new SPP[]
                    {
                        new SPP("id_usuario", idUsuario.ToString()),
                        new SPP("old_pass", old_pass.ToString()),
                        new SPP("new_pass", new_pass.ToString())
                    });

        if (tablaResultado.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (tablaResultado.Rows[0] != null)
            {
                result = (int.Parse(tablaResultado.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString()));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlException)
    {
        throw sqlException;
    }
}
```

I have multiple methods which follow the same pattern and all of those works, I have been trying to get this to work for awhile now, and I'm sure I'm overlooking something very, very obvious. Either way I cannot find it right now so I was hoping someone could refresh my memory or give me a tip.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger? Are you getting past the line where you assign the value, or is there an exception?

Comment: @RufusL It doesn't throw a exception because the stored procedure and the rest of the code works, this result is just to inform the user whenever the change was made or not. As in 1= success and 0 = error, but the debugger isn't telling me the value isn't sticking

Comment: When you say it works, have you stepped through it after setting a breakpoint? are you sure it sets result?

Comment: The code does not compile. Stepping through it is either impossible or meaningless since either there is no IL at all, or else the IL there is is from a different version of the source code (if there were once a version that did compile) which make debugging meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code only assigns a value to the `result` variable if two different conditions both happen to be `true`. That is, if the row count is > 0 and the first row is non-null. The compiler is telling you, completely legitimately, that your code contains a path to the `return` statement where the variable being used hasn't been assigned a value yet.

You need to decide what the method should return if either of those conditions are *not* true, and then assign that value to the `result` variable as part of its initialization.

EDIT:

To be clear: it seems you may be overlooking the possibility that your code won't successfully execute the stored procedure. But it can only return a value to be assigned to `result` when those two conditions are true. You either need to pick a default value that is reasonable to return when one or the other of the conditions aren't true, or you need to fix the code so that those conditions are always both true (and so the SP always executes successfully).

Comment: The problem was in the stored procedure, I was using a if @@rowcount = -, return -1 if not return 0.  So following your logic which confirmed my suspicious I changed the return to select and it worked. So thanks a lot ;D